# Как почистить linux?

Tags: linux, unix

Не так давно начал пользоваться linux, ставил нужное по, различные пакет и не парился. А щя задумался, собственно вопрос. Как чистить linux? Тут много файлов мне не знакомых, трудно понят нужны они или нет если нет то какие?

В windows все было ясно и понятно что надо что нет, куда надо лесть куда не стоит и что будет если я удалю тот или иной файл. А здесь черт ногу сломит ) Может знающие пользователи дадите пару советов или материал какой стоит почитать?

Comment: Ох, ну и вопросики. Начните, например, с [этого](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FHS).

Comment: лишнего ничего нет. Все времянки находятся в /tmp и /var/tmp. Логи, которые /var/log. Все ваше "лишнее" в домашнем каталоге

Comment: Не парьтесь дальше. Вы его рано или поздно переустановите, и все почистится само. Просто держите под рукой файлик, в котором описаны необходимые репозитории, и установленные - нужные вам пакеты, что быстро поднять свежую систему до рабочего состояния. Почистить немного можно в `~/.config`, `~/.cache`, `~/.local` Если переходите c KDE на GTK- based DE или наоборот.

Comment: @maint - спорное утверждение. Соглашусь в том, что удалять пакеты с диска - не особо-то и нужно обычно, но я вот поставил себе, скажем, FTP-server для отладки некоего скрипта, дальше он мне не нужен, а ресурсы жрет. Можно бы и  выключить.

Comment: чушь несете. Для того что бы поставить, нужно знать что ставить и что включать. А здесь понятия не имеет человек, что ему нужно.

Comment: Правильный способ "почистить Linux" -- соберите **свою** систему из исходников: LFS, BuildRoot, собственная ручная сборка (через Makefile) из исходников начиная с (кросс-)компилятора GCC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос где там все ясно и понятно весьма холиварен, оставим его в стороне.
Пакеты в linux в целом удаляются примерно так же, как и ставятся, например для Ubuntu (Debian)

```
$ sudo apt-get install some-package - ставит пакет
$ sudo apt-get remove some-package - удаляет пакет, но оставляет конфиг-файлы
$ sudo apt-get purge some-package - удаляет пакет "начисто" вместе со всеми конфигами
```

Для других дистрибутивов: `man package-manager-name` или `package-manager-name --help`.

Залезать в /etc, /bin, /usr и т.п. и удалять оттуда файлы вручную стоит только в случае, когда Вы очень хорошо понимаете, что делаете (впрочем как и в случае Program files в виндах).

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, разбираться в linux не сложнее чем в Windows. Надо только понять основные принципы, и все встанет на свои места. Для понимания структуры каталогов можно начать отсюда https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FHS
Для очистки системы от лишних файлов есть графические утилиты, например, bleachbit или UbuntuTweak. Ненужные пакеты, установленные как зависимости для других пакетов, удаляются менеджерами пакетов. В графических интерфейсах для менеджеров пакетов есть, как правило, соответствующие пункты в настройках или меню.